# Uiimageview shows nothing after get image

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm new at Xcode. I'm trying to get an image that's stored in firebase. But. when I try to put the code, it's showing nothing. I'm trying to print the image, its nil. There are a lot of tutorials, but every one of them I don't understand.

```
func loadUserDetail() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    imgStorage = Storage.storage().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let email = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""
        let address = value?["address"] as? String ?? ""
        let image = value?["image"] as? String ?? ""
        let phone = value?["phone"] as? String ?? ""
        let user = User(name: username, email: email, address: address, image : image, phone : phone)

        self.fullnameTF.text = user.name
        self.emailTF.text = user.email
        self.PhoneTF.text = user.phone

        let storageRef = self.imgStorage.child("User/\(userID!)/UserPic")
        storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.imgProfilePicture.image = image
            }
        }
    }) 
    { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I think the problem is when I'm uploading the image that I get from picker: it's showing that the image size is 0kb.

```
let fileData = NSData() // get data...
let storageRef = self.imgStorage.child("User/\(userUiD!)/UserPic")
storageRef.putData(fileData as Data).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in
// When the image has successfully uploaded, we get it's download URL
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
    if (error == nil) {
        if let downloadUrl = url {
            // Make you download string
            let downloadString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
            self.ref.child("User").child(userUiD!).child("image").setValue(downloadString)        
        }
    } else {
        print("Error To Saved")
    }
})
}}
```

Comment: Is this line being called `self.imgProfilePicture.image = image`? Is the image actually there (not nil).

Comment: i think the problem is when im uploading the image, when i check in the storage, its shown 0KB

Comment: why you put empty data object in fileData ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace `let fileData = NSData()` with your image data .  NSData() create only empty data object with 0kb  so you should convert your image to data like :

```
 var fileData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)  // image is UIImage which you get from Picker

or 

 var fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)
```